# How does one remove all files with * in a directory using sh library in python?

Tags: python, shell

I was trying to delete all files that started with the word slurm using the [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/#tutorials) library. In the command line I would do:

```
rm slurm*
```

such a command would work in a shell.

But when I do:

```
sh.rm("./slurm*")
```

and other variants (like only "slurm*" or build the command first using sh.Command and so) it thows me the same error:

```
  RAN: '/bin/rm slurm*'

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
/bin/rm: cannot remove `slurm*': No such file or directory
```

Is that a bug with the library or is it that I can't find the correct docs to know how to execute commands correctly using `sh`? Or is there a better way of running that command in python?

Comment: See: https://amoffat.github.io/sh/#glob-expansion

Comment: @Rufflewind: Well, this should be an answer.

Comment: I see, so its called glob-expansion...no wonder I couldn't google it effectively X) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it is not a bug in the library.  When you type 'rm slurm*' in shell.  The shell itself first expands the slurm* pattern to a list of files that start with slurm and then calls 'rm' executable passing the list of filenames.  The rm program loops over the list and uses 'unlink' system call on each of the filenames.

Take a look at the source of sh library [here](https://github.com/amoffat/sh/blob/master/sh.py#L1292), you can see that it just uses 'exec' system call to start a child process without expanding the arguments.  The rm command doesn't know how use the list.

So in your case you either have to use glob expansion, as Rufflewind pointed out  [here](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/#glob-expansion) or you can call some sort of shell with '-c' to pass the command. The shell will do this expansion for you.

The later case is not very efficient and somewhat error prone, but if you really want to do it here is an example how to do it.

```
sh.bash ('-c rm slurm*')
```

Again this is not a right way to do things.  But in rare cases you have to resort to such things

Comment: Thanks for the help! But why does that work? Why that be a problem, I don't understand the issue.

Comment: I did little bit more of the research and edited the answer.  Hope now you understand the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python's `glob` module for glob expansion.

```
import os, glob
os.remove(*glob.glob('slurm*'))
```

Even reading the code makes me thirsty for some slurm.

Comment: It does what you try to do with `sh.rm("./slurm*")`. It's better to avoid using `sh.bash ('-c rm slurm*')`, since passing commands to the shell as a raw string can lead to hard to find bugs or potential remote code execution exploits.